# How to make Widget small as its parent allows in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to create a Widget with the same layout as bellow.

```
+===================+ => A not fixed height widget
|  ---------------  |
| |               | |
| |               | | => Image()
|  ---------------  |
|  ~~~~~~~~~        | => Text()
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~    | => Text()
+===================+
```

How could I make the `Image Widget` small as its parent allows in Flutter? I also as much as possible if I have a big parent Widget, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expanded` inside the `Column` would do the trick you wanted. You can change height and width of the `Container`. Expanded `flex` will fill the percentage of the parent height.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question5 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //you can change width here
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //you can change height here
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Image.network(
                'https://www.visioncritical.com/hubfs/Imported_Blog_Media/BLG_Andrew-G_-River-Sample_09_13_12.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Some title here',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Some subtitle here',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested your solution but according my last exposition. Your solution will let the write space below the second `Text`.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm Try out changes I made in the answer

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm Accept the answer once your issue is solved. thanks

Comment: Thank @pskink for your suggest. I tested my solution and got that over engineered.